# OpenVPN DNS resolution issue on router (EdgeOS)

Tags: domain-name-system, openvpn, ip, ubiquiti-edgerouter

I've been using OpenVPN client over vtun interface and all works as expected only if the remote VPN server name (in the OpenVPN config) is the IP address. When I use the DNS name as part of the OpenVPN config "remote" OpenVPN cannot establish connection.

The same hostname is being resolved correctly from the Edge Router box at the same time, when OpenVPN reports `"openvpn[1381]: RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address: SERVERNAMECOMESHERE Temporary failure in name resolution"`.

It looks like for some reason OpenVPN cannot use DNS service or DNS query because they are forbidden in the default FW rules.

What I am missing?

Comment: Hard to tell.  You really haven't given us much information here.  It seems likely that your guess is correct, something is broken about  your DNS or firewall rules.  Are you sure you have DNS servers properly set on the router at all?  Can it resolve any DNS names?

Comment: Yes, DNS is ok on the router, at the very same time, when openvpn cannot resolve the remote host, i can resolve it by dig, ping or nslookup from the router itself